# How to properly manipulate a string column in a data frame in R?

Tags: regex, r, string, dataframe

I have a data.frame with a string column that contains periods e.g "a.b.c.X". I want to split out the string by periods and retain the third segment e.g. "c" in the example given. Here is what I'm doing.

```
> df = data.frame(v=c("a.b.a.X", "a.b.b.X", "a.b.c.X"), b=seq(1,3))
> df
        v b
1 a.b.a.X 1
2 a.b.b.X 2
3 a.b.c.X 3
```

And what I want is

```
> df = data.frame(v=c("a.b.a.X", "a.b.b.X", "a.b.c.X"), b=seq(1,3))
> df
        v b
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c 3
```

I'm attempting to use `within`, but I'm getting strange results. The value in the first row in the first column is being repeated.

```
> get = function(x) { unlist(strsplit(x, "\\."))[3] }
> within(df, v <- get(as.character(v)))
  v b
1 a 1
2 a 2
3 a 3
```

What is the best practice for doing this? What am I doing wrong?

---

Update:
Here is the solution I used from @agstudy's answer:

```
> df = data.frame(v=c("a.b.a.X", "a.b.b.X", "a.b.c.X"), b=seq(1,3))
> get = function(x) gsub(".*?[.].*?[.](.*?)[.].*", '\\1', x)
> within(df, v <- get(v))                                                                                                                                                               
  v b
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some regular expression you can do :

```
gsub(".*?[.].*?[.](.*?)[.].*", '\\1', df$v)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Or more concise:

```
gsub("(.*?[.]){2}(.*?)[.].*", '\\2', v)
```

Comment: regexes always require me to do some thinking so I appreciate it when someone else does the thinking instead. +1

Comment: @TylerRinker thanks, although I was lazy in this one :)(lazy greediness)

Comment: @agstudy thanks! I was struggling to find the right method to do what I wanted with a regex in R. Previously I was doing the transformation in perl first before importing the data in R but I knew there had to be a way to do it in R. So which is faster, `strsplit/unlist` or `gsub`?

Comment: @drsnyder I think `gsub` here is faster, It is vectorized the other solution use a loop. But you should benchmark to verify this.

Comment: How can I get the gsub to work within a data frame? I want to be able to run a function across the data frame and have the values updated in-place. The @TylerRinker solution from above does this correctly but the gsub method you provided does not. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with `within` but with your `get` function. It returns a single character (`"a"`) which gets recycled when added to your data.frame. Your code should look like this:

```
get.third <- function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, "\\."), `[[`, 3)
within(df, v <- get.third(as.character(v)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What is the difference between using `strsplit` + `unlist` in this context and `sapply`? Specifically why is the return value of `get` being recycled and not individually applied to each row in the data frame?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution:

```
df[, "v"] <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df[, "v"]), "\\."))[, 3]

## > df
##   v b
## 1 a 1
## 2 b 2
## 3 c 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "what am I doing wrong" is that the bit of code that you thought was extracting the third element of each split string was actually putting *all* the elements of *all* your strings in a single vector, and then returning the third element of that:

```
get = function(x) { 
  splits = strsplit(x, "\\.")
  print("All the elements: ")
  print(unlist(splits))
  print("The third element:")
  print(unlist(splits)[3])
  # What you actually wanted:
  third_chars = sapply(splits, function (x) x[3])
}
within(df, v2 <- get(as.character(v)))
```